# show other images from same gallery

Tags: gallery

suppose you are viewing a single image from the gallery. You have both previous and next links there (for navigation).
but
is there a way to also show all the other images from the same gallery in the same page (for example i want to show other images from same gallery)

if there is a way then can anyone please provide me the simplest code please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At it's very simplest, add this to your theme's `attachment.php`

```
<?php do_shortcode('[gallery id="' . $post->post_parent . '"]'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

TheDeadMedic answer is real one.in Suppose you like to get from plugin means follow the below Link.It'll Helpful for you.This Plugin is very Famous [Gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/).You are Clear with my solution?:)